# Ensure that all PDF content is transferred to the output file while merging

Tags: php, pdf, fpdi

I'm trying to merge multiple PDF files using the tool `Setasign/FPDI` along with their parser `FPDI PDF-Parser`.

Some PDF files can have drawings like signatures before they are merged. The problem is that after the merging, those drawings are gone.

I'm looking for a solution to ensure that all PDF content is transferred to the final merged output file.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```php
    private function mergeFiles()
    {
        $fpdi = new Fpdi();

        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $this->mergePDFFile($fpdi, $file->getFilePath());
        }

        $fpdi->Output($outputFilePath, 'F');
    }


    private function mergePDFFile(Fpdi $pdf, $filePath)
    {
        $pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile($filePath);

        for ($pageNo = 1; $pageNo <= $pageCount; $pageNo++) {
            $templateId = $pdf->importPage($pageNo);
            $size       = $pdf->getTemplateSize($templateId);
            $pdf->AddPage($size['orientation']);
            $pdf->useTemplate($templateId, null, null, null, null, true);
        }
    }
```

**The original files before merging**

[image: The original files before merging]

**The merged files with the unexptected result**

[image: The merged files with the unexptected result]

Comment: I don't know a lot about this specific library, but reading [this](https://manuals.setasign.com/fpdi-manual/v2/limitations/#index-3), if those "drawings" are actually "annotation" (like you'd make using Adobe Acrobat), then this applies: "Dynamic content like form fields or any other page annotations can't be attached...So FPDI is not able to import this kind of content."

Comment: If upgrading to FPDI 2.x and above is feasible, please check if it resolves the issue. If not, see if explicitly importing drawing objects from source using `FPDI PDF-Parser`  is working out. After parsing and extracting drawing objects from source, you can import using `useTemplate()`

Comment: Another option is to flatten the annotations first - you can do this with `qpdf --flatten-annotations=all in.pdf out.pdf`.

Comment: @johnwhitington thank you so much for this idea. flattening seems to be the solution. I have tried to output a file using ghostscript with the flag `-dPreserveAnnots` set to `false` and it works for now.